# Deploy app created with docker-compose to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecr

> **Final goal:** To deploy a ready-made cryptocurrency exchange on AWS.

I have [setup a readymade server by 0xProject](https://github.com/0xProject/0x-launch-kit) by running the [following command](https://github.com/0xProject/0x-launch-kit#quick-start) on my local machine:

```
npx @0x/launch-kit-wizard && docker-compose up
```

This command creates a `docker-compose.yml` file which has multiple container definitions and starts the exchange on http://localhost:3001/

I need to deploy this to AWS for which I'm following [this Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yjb5kfRUw0A)

- I have created a registry user with appropriate permissions
- An EC2 instance is created
- ECR repository is created
- AWS CLI is configured

As per AWS instructions, I'm retrieving an authentication token and authenticating Docker client to registry:

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-2 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <docker-id-given-by-AWS>.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
```

I'm trying to build the docker image:

```
docker build -t testdockerregistry .
```

Now, since in this case, we have `docker-compose.yml` instead of `Dockerfile` - when I try to build the image - it throws the following error:

```
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: CreateFile C:\Users\hp\Desktop\xxx\Dockerfile: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I tried building image from docker-compose itself [as per this guide](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/build/), which fails with the following message:

```
postgres uses an image, skipping
frontend uses an image, skipping
mesh uses an image, skipping
backend uses an image, skipping
nginx uses an image, skipping
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: It seems like your docker-compose just references images, can you confirm if they're public or private?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams They're public yeah!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [aws ecs cli-compose](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cmd-ecs-cli-compose.html) command from the ECS CLI.

By using this command it will translate the `docker-compose` file you create into a ECS [Task Definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definitions.html).

If you're interested in finding out more about the CLI take a read of the AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_CLI.html).

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, instead of using the AWS ECS CLI directly, is to use the new [`docker/compose-cli`](https://github.com/docker/compose-cli)

> This CLI tool makes it easy to run Docker containers and Docker Compose applications in the cloud using either Amazon Elastic Container Service (ECS) or Microsoft Azure Container Instances (ACI) using the Docker commands you already know.

See "[Docker Announces Open Source Compose for AWS ECS & Microsoft ACI](https://www.infoq.com/news/2020/10/docker-announces-compose-ecs-aci/) " from [Aditya Kulkarni](https://twitter.com/ThisisAadi).
It references "[Docker Open Sources Compose for Amazon ECS and Microsoft ACI](https://www.docker.com/blog/open-source-cloud-compose/)" from  [Chris Crone](https://twitter.com/ccrone), Engineer @docker:

> While implementing these integrations, we wanted to make sure that existing CLI commands were not impacted.
> We also wanted an architecture that would make it easy to add new backends and provide SDKs in popular languages. We achieved this with the following architecture:

[image: https://res.infoq.com/news/2020/10/docker-announces-compose-ecs-aci/en/resources/1CLI%20Architecture-1602557186982.png]